# R delete columns based on character contained in the column name

Tags: r, subset

how do I delete columns based on a condition, when the condition is a character contained in the column name?
For instance, following a series of inner joins I get a lot of redundant columns:

```
client.x, client.y, age.y. age.x
  132        132       23    23
  112        112       12    12
```

I would like a one liner to remove all columns containing for instance the ".x", to end up with:

```
client.y, age.y. 
  132       23
  112       12
```

Thanks

Comment: Use the `df1[grep("\\.x", names(df1), invert=TRUE)]`

Comment: `dplyr::select(df, -contains(".x"))`

Comment: Thanks, it works. Can we use a modified version of this code to rename columns by removing the ".x"?

Comment: what do you want the new names to be?

Comment: you might want to go back and look at your `join`, because you could probably clean all this up back there

Comment: For renaming, you can use `sub` i.e. `names(df1) <- sub("\\.x$", "", names(df1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `grep` to identify the column names that have `.x` and with the use of `invert=TRUE`, it returns the index of other columns

```
df1[grep("\\.x", names(df1), invert=TRUE)]
#    client.y age.y.
#1      132     23
#2      112     12
```